# Display extra information adjacent to system_settings_form() output

Tags: forms, nodes, theming

I have a properly constructed set of data coming out of a call to `system_settings_form()`.  How can I add to that data to display additional items on the form page?

I'm currently trying (and failing with):

```
// ...inside drupal_get_form callback
// $form has some form elements in it
$return =  system_settings_form($form);
if (!hay_problemas()){
    $return['warning'] = array(
        '#type' => 'div',
        '#class' => 'warning',
        '#markup' => 'WARNING:  Filesystem permission are broken'
    );
}
return $return;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this must be

```
// ...inside drupal_get_form callback
// $form has some form elements in it

if (!hay_problemas()){
  $form['warning'] = array(
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('warning')),
    '#markup' => t('WARNING:  Filesystem permission are broken'),
    '#weight' => -10, //set position relative to other $form['key']
  );
}

return system_settings_form($form);
```

Comment: Nailed it.  Can you recommend a good tutorial for this type of work?

Comment: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#weightval for allowed form properties and http://drupal.org/node/206761 for module settings page, the best place is to see how other module implements their settings pages

Comment: Thanks, the first link was what i meant.  I more or less had a handle on the second part.

Comment: Also, take a look at `drupal_set_message()`, as it might be better to display warnings. See http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/7